# Check empty fields on mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this function on my node REST API

```
var router = express.Router();

/*router.get('/getUsers', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });
});*/

router.route('/Users')
  .get(function(req,res){
      User.find(function(err,users){
        if(err)
          res.send(err);

        console.log('GET request');
        res.json(users);
      });
})
  .post(function(req,res){
      var user = new User();
      user.name = req.body.name;
      user.lastName = req.body.lastName;

      if(!user.name || !user.lastName){
        user.save(function(err){
          if(err)
            res.send(err);

          console.log('POST request');
          res.json({message:'Usuario creado'});
        });
      }else{
        res.json({message:'Campos vacíos'});
      }

  });
```

It works but when I a send a POST  request with empty parameters it saves a document in mongoDB without the `name` and `lastName` fields and `if(!user.name || !user.lastName)` doesn't work to avoid it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well
`if (!user.name || !user.lastName) ...`
checks that at least one of both must be empty / `null` / `undefined` and only then saves it - exactly what you describe as your problem :)

So I guess you want something like

```
if(user.name && user.lastName)...
```

Or alternatively swap the code blocks in `if` / `else` branch

```
if(!user.name || !user.lastName){
  res.json({message:'Campos vacíos'});
}else{
  user.save(function(err){
    if(err)
      res.send(err);
    console.log('POST request');
    res.json({message:'Usuario creado'});
  });
}
```